# HoloEverywhere not running: R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android

hi i have a problem with HoloEverywhere i always get the error:

```
R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

i did the following:
i imported the holoeverywhere and action bar libarary. then i set the theme to holo in my manifest file. at the end i changed my `extends Activity` to `extends com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.sherlock.SActivity`

I also cleaned my project with no success

what could be the problem?
in the holo project i have no errors

EDIT: I also have two other errors

```
The hierarchy of the type MainActivity is inconsistent
```

&

```
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Comment: Is you R.java file being generated. If not, in the problem view it will give you a reason why. What does it say?

Comment: And what does the problems view show, usually this means there is a problem with your resources (layout XMLs etc.)

Comment: now i have two other errors: The hierarchy of the type MainActivity is inconsistent & Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: This is probably a hastle, but I would recomend copying and pasting all of your code into a new project. That solved a similar problem for me

Comment: i started a whole new project and still have this issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If using Eclipse, try using the Organize imports function (CTRL+SHIFT+O) to make sure that you import all needed classes into your Java file.
2. Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.
3. Check that there are no errors in your resource files (especially layout files), as this will prevent the generation of the R.java file. An easy way of doing this in Eclipse is to open the Problems View: Window -> Show View -> Other -> Problems

Comment: now i have two other errors: The hierarchy of the type MainActivity is inconsistent & Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies